# Why isn't Ansible Setting the Correct Directory Permissions?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set folder permission for an SFTP share with ansible.

I'm first creating a sftp user group:

```
sudo addgroup sftp
```

then creating a new user:

```
sudo useradd -m sftpuser -g sftp
```

then finally giving users full access to a directory:

```
sudo chmod 700 /home/sftpuser/
```

I'm trying to replicate that last step with ansible

```
  - name: Change folder permission
    file:
      path: /home/stanley/
      recurse: yes
      mode: 700
    become: true
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How do I replicate the effect of sudo chmod 700 /home/sftpuser/ in ansible?

Comment: There's a bad practice in your code that would be revealed by running your task through `ansible-lint` and that is probably the source of your problem => `mode: "0700"`

Comment: I'm agree with @Zeitounator.
On one side, you should quote your mode either in single or double quotes and on the other side, you _should_ use 4 digit octal preferably.